# How to keep types in proguard but not ones matching a specific name or pattern?

Tags: android, proguard

I would like to specify something like

```
  -keep class {
    public static int *;  // unless the constant name is 'ABC' perhaps !ABC   ??????
     }
```

Same for method names etc.  Is there anyway to do this in Proguard? So basically I want a -keep rule but excluding elements that match a particular string or regular expression.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done?

I guess, the answer is yes.

[Proguard Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification) says: "class names can actually be comma-separated lists of class names, with optional ! negators, just like file name filters."

Comment: That would be good. Not clear on what the syntax would look like exactly.